# Portable HD transfer speed decelerates to 0 KB

Tags: windows-8, external-hard-drive, file-transfer

I have a Western Digital 2 TB portable HDD. My laptop is running Windows 8.1.

I'm having trouble transferring files from one to the other. On occasion, transferring files works fine but sometimes I see the transfer speed decelerate to 0kb and no files will transfer.

When this happens it takes a system restart to get the portable HDD working again. It fails with this error  `error 0x8800701e3 the request failed due to a fatal device hardware error`.

Stranger still is that when this occurs certain system operations like emptying the recycle bin become unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

If the USB drive is formated in NTFS then it also has an internal recycle bin which is erased when you empty the recycle bin.
It could be:

- A physical disk defect (try checking disk errors)
- A defective usb cable
- Corrupted USB drivers

Comment: Yeah is NTFS. Scan disk Shows no errors. Im pretty sure the usb cable is ok because it's brand new. How might I investigate the USB driver?

Comment: Under device properties reinstall driver. Have you tested the drive in another PC?

Comment: Thanks. I will try both of these later. There doesnt seem to be specific western digital drivers on their site so hopefully windows will get it right.